# Does date_default_timezone_set() effects time()?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

If I set a **time zone** like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Will it affect the value of `time()`?

Comment: Did you try to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Note the GMT on the end.

Also read the first comment on the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) for time()

> The documentation should have this info. The function time() returns
>   always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC).

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
echo "UTC:".time(); 
echo "<br>"; 

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki"); 
echo "Europe/Helsinki:".time(); 
echo "<br>"; 
?>
```

Local time as string can be get by strftime() and local timestamp (if ever needed) by mktime().

Comment: Thanks i was just confused.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not. Your system knows the *absolute time*. Timestamps (`time()`) represent *absolute* timestamps. Timezone settings only affect *human readable* time formats as produced by `date()`, since those are relative to a specific location on earth (because 12:00 noon it typically when the sun is highest in the sky, and that varies between locations).